# Showing the number of folders in a given place

Tags: javascript, discord.js

why is my code not working? I want to do something like that when the bot turns on I get a message to the console about the number of servers it is in.

```
const serversFolders = readdirSync(dirServers)

const servers = parseInt(serversFolders)

table.addRow(servers)

console.log(table.toString())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would encourage you to thoroughly read [ask]. You haven't provided any details about what is or isn't happening, what expected behavior is and what happens instead and no mention of any errors

Comment: instead of displaying the number of files it displays a number, as if the server ID but it is not the ID of any servers that are there. Or maybe there is a shortcode that shows the number of servers my bot is on

Comment: Theres already a `guilds` property for your Discord.Client Object

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the number of servers your bot is in simply do:

```
console.log(client.guilds.cache.size);
```